# Load CSS file conditionally

Tags: functions

Trying to load CSS file conditionally – only for specific pages with the following:

```
add_filter('tablepress_use_default_css', 'tablepress_css_conditional_load');
function tablepress_css_conditional_load($load) {
return ((!is_page(array( 229, 9 ))) ? false : $load);
}
```

For some reason it is not working. To make sure that there is no mistake in the IDs I replaced `! is_page( array( 229, 9 ) )` with `! is_page()` and with `! is_single()` but still it is not working. Deactivated other plugins, changed theme, still nothing. The CSS name is verified with the plugin author. When the above part is replaced with `is_single()` the code works in a way that lets the CSS load for any page – not for posts. However the point is to load only for the named pages. Which is the correction needed?

Comment: is_single() is working correctly https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_single/

Comment: @StefanoTombolini Yes, but the point is to have the css file loading only for the specific pages 229 and 9.

Comment: Do !is_single / !is_page work as expected? It should load only on posts / pages.

Comment: @StefanoTombolini No, they do not work at all: if I use either !is_single or !is_page the css file is loading both for pages and posts.